# Cannot invoke "isValidEmail" with an argument error

Tags: swift, email-validation

I am new to swift and facing a little issue of validating email

```
//Login API CALL
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var userModel = UserModel();
    var data_info: [String:AnyObject] =
    [
        "udid" : "",
        "email" : "someemail",
        "password" : "soempass"
    ];
    var checkInput = UserModel.isValidEmail(data_info["email"]); //Error here
    if (checkInput) {
      var isTrue = UserModel.doLogin(data_info:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>.self);
    }
}

//Validate Email
func isValidEmail(testStr:AnyObject) -> Bool {
    println("validate emilId: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    var emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    var result = emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
    return result
}
```

Is there any type issue? Should i change AnyObject to String?
UserModel is an external class which validate email Address
Thanks is advance!

Comment: i think its time to take some break
spelling mistake var checkInput = userModel.isValidEmail(data_info["email"]); //Error here

Answer (score 1):

Try with small "u", that's the instance, with capital "U" it's the class

```
userModel.isValidEmail(data_info["email"]);
```